# NHibernate: How do I combine an IQuery with an ICriteria?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I want fetch a list that uses both IQuery and ICriterias.. Is it possible? How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Linq to Objects...

```
var listUsingCriteria = session.CreateCriteria(...).List<Something>();
var listUsingQuery = session.CreateQuery(...).List<Something>();
var allElements = listUsingCriteria.Concat(listUsingQuery);
```

Of course, after adding the elements, you can sort, filter, etc.